# I don't see site_url and home_url fields in wp_options table (phpMyAdmin)?

Tags: database, options, migration, site-url, home-url

I wanted to show you this issue. This is happening first time with me in my 10 years career, I have cloned many sites to another domain in past but this is for the first time when I do not see the "site URL and home options" under Wp_Options (phpmyadmin)

This is the domain name which I cloned

**https://13cabsonline.com.au**

and this is the destination domain

**https://silverservice.sydney/**

I have downloaded and restored files via Backup Widget.
Uploaded the file manager + databases and connected the databases with a user too.

But the issue is that I am not able to find the options under Wp_Options in phpmyadmin.

**For example:** A normal look of `wp_options` is like this http://prnt.sc/o1724k
but I see this https://prnt.sc/o172as

Can you please have a look at it as there is no video or blog about it on the internet. This is strange to me.

Comment: might be your database not imported fully on `phpmyadmin` kindly double check your SQL file with the editor is `wp_options` table exists or not.

Comment: Have a look at your next page (or 2) in the wp_options ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Check wp-config.php. It's possible to define these values there, in which case they won't be available as settings, which means they won't be saved in the database.

> It is possible to set the site URL manually in the wp-config.php file.
>
> Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where “example.com” is the correct location of your site.
>
> ```
> define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
> define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
> ```
>
> This is not necessarily the best fix, it’s just hard-coding the values into the site itself. You won’t be able to edit them on the General settings page anymore when using this method.

— https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#edit-wp-config-php

If this was done on the original site, the corresponding values won't exist in `wp_options`. The solution would be to either change the values in wp-config.php, or remove these lines from wp-config.php and then insert the desired values into `wp_options` manually.

Comment: Thank you, i actually, copy pasted that code as well, but that did not solve the issue. But i went inside the phpmyadmin and clicked on the wp_options and then clicked on the search bar, i searched siteurl and home and i found both values. Actually for someone unknown reason, siteurl and home was hidden.

What have i done now? I have deleted the whole cpanel, and created a cpanel again for the site https://silverservice.sydney/

I have added the new user and connected the wp_config.php with the database. But still i am getting this error --> Error establishing a database connection

Answer (score 1):

Please check ID no. 13496, 13497 in page 22 of the table list

[image: Screenshot of table]

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved. I deleted the cpanel and recreated cpanel again in my hosting. Then i just restore everything. It worked.

I am going to add a screenshot here which will help others to find the hidden siteurl and home field --> [image]

[image]

[image]

You can search siteurl as well to edit the hidden field.

My official website is this --> https://www.khalsa-website-designers.net/

You can contact me, if you are having the same issue, and want me to help you. I will dafinatly help you for free.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is really a problem. I think you can try using Google’s add url from LinkBox http://linkbox.pro/ru/google-addurl . The problem can be solved this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the search option and searched for "siteurl" and "home" and thus I have got them under OPTIONS. You can see below how I did it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is just to open the SQL file in a code editor. Search for `siteurl` and then replace the URLs with your preferred way and save the file. after then import the SQL to your database.

Have fun debugging!